# Vercel response.json() returns as HTML in production

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vite, vercel

I made a react app with vite. I fetch json from my data file locally via

```
const response = await fetch('/src/data/dishes.json');
```

In the network tab, I can see the response fine on my localhost. But in production I return html.

[image]

Below is my `vercel.json` file

```
{
  "rewrites":  [
    {"source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/"}
  ]
}
```

What do I have to change to fetch json properly in production?